# What is the full form of RT resistor in RT?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Here is the datasheet of the TI switcher using in my design
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54620.pdf

Could you please help to find the full-form of **RT** in RT resistor?
Attached is the relevant screenshot for reference.
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks
VT

Comment: There is no image linked.

Comment: Updated now. Sorry Gilles,

Answer (score 1):

RT means **resistor timer** for an Astable Clock with external R or external logic clock for synchronous operation, possibly used for N phase shifted parallel converters or EMI or inductor property purposes.

Comment: So is it like, it has some definite C inside the chip and as the external R varies, the value of RC varies which causes the clock generation?

Comment: yes, thats what the spec says for R values.  We know it also has some PLL but this would not be the VCO input hence  the R bias or over-ride or RT/CLK input.

Comment: So my concept guess was correct but never knew the name.

Comment: I too, guessed,  with this understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "the full-form of RT" means that you want to determine the value of RT, read Section 8.4.1.